# SCSS Horizontal Display

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, sass

My code looks something like this:

```
    <div class="container">
      <button class="leftbutton"> // these buttons control horizontal scrolling
      <ul class="scrollbar">
      <button class="rightbutton">
    </div>
```

And my styling looks like this:

```
.scrollbar{
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-columns: max-content;
  overflow: hidden;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  padding: 0;
}

.container{
  position: relative;
}

.leftButton {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.rightButton {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

The problem is that the content of the scroll bar covers the left button. Any idea how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: You have an incorrect html.

Comment: As @s.kuznetsov mentioned your html is incomplete I'd suggest checking it with this [HTML validator](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input)

Comment: @s.kuznetsov my HTML doesn't actually look like that, it's much longer and it's correctly written, this is just the general structure so you can see which classes correspond to which elements.

Comment: @Parco see above ^

Comment: @kb753 Welcome to Stack Overflow! You need to put at least enough code so it's not incomplete. We have no idea if your real code is correct or not. You put a broken example, so every answer you will get will be "your HTML is wrong" regardless what you put in the comments. Please read [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You should also update your title to something more meaningful. This has nothing to do with _SCSS Horizontal Display_ - since that doesn't describe any thing. This is really just an HTML/CSS issue. JS/React/SASS aren't really a factor here.

Comment: Use `z-index: 9999` for `.leftButton` and `position: relative` for `.container`